# Error in compiling cocos2d-x project for android when using json

Tags: android, json, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, android.mk

I'am using `cocos2d-x` version `3.3rc`
In some of my class I `#include "cocos2d/external/json/writer.h"`
when I want to compile my project to make android apk, by running `build_native.py` script, it shows the following error to me:

```
fatal error: cocos2d/external/json/writer.h: No such file or directory
```

But I include its file in my android.mk file with this syntax:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external/json \
```

And here is the complete android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)


LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                    ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                    ../../Classes/Database/CacheData.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external/json 

#LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocosdenshion_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += box2d_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += chipmunk_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_extension_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += json_external_static


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
In cocos2d-x version 3.3 the default **android.mk** file that generated is sufficient and all other library was imported. Then the default android.mk file in jni folder was completely integrated with other .mk files. i see that the files in json folder that located in **'cocos2s/external/json'** are .h files and there is no dependency between them and other cocos2d files and library.
then I simply copy this folder to my Classes folder and include them locally.Now **the problem is solved** :)